# Objective-C Sockets Send and Receive on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm very new to Objective-C and would like to communicate between an iOS app which I'm working on and my Python 3 socket server (which works). The problem is I don't know how to use sockets in Objective-C and don't know where to start when installing libraries in Xcode 8. For now I just want to be able to send data to the server and receive a response back on the iOS device. I have seen sys.socket.h but again, I don't know how to use it, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I used [SocketRocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket). I am posting some of the code of it from my old project. I don't know if that still works but you might get the idea of using it.

1. Connecting to server

`NSMutableURLRequest *pushServerRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://192.168.1.1"]];
    [pushServerRequest setValue:@"WebSocket" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Upgrade"];
    [pushServerRequest setValue:@"Upgrade" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [pushServerRequest setValue:"somekey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"];
    SRWebSocket *wsmain = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:pushServerRequest]; //Declare this as a global variable in a header file
    wsmain.delegate=self;
    [wsmain open];`

2. Delegate Methods

`-(void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
    {
        NSLog(@"Message %@",message);
    }
    - (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket
    {    NSLog(@"Connected");
    }`

3. Sending Commands

   `[wsmain send:commands];`

By sending commands, you will receive a response in `didReceiveMessage` method.

Comment: thanks, what event did you use to catch the data on the server side? I am using WebSocket for node, listening for 'message' event but not seeing anything, data should be going through

Answer (score 0):

have you seen https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket?
It's easy to use socket

```
NSString *host = @"10.70.0.22";
int port = 1212;

_socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];

NSError *error = nil;
[_socket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

delegate

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port{
NSLog(@"success");
}
-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err{
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"error %@",err);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self connectToServer];
    });
}else{
    NSLog(@"disconnect");
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, I think I have managed to install the library. How do I go about communication with my python server without needing pages of code, I only want to do this in the ViewController.m file for new.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. In the end I went with Swift 3 and used SwiftSockets, its now working well with my python server and can send the requests I need it to

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [socket.io](http://socket.io). It has server libraries and a iOS client library written in Swift. It's API is quite extensive.